# how do I change the template used in wordpress magento integration by fishpig

Tags: template, wordpress, default, integrate

I have recently installed the magento wordpress instegration by fishpig.
[extension located here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-3795.html)
I have installed it correctly and it works fine however the default template is set to 2columns-left.phtml and I wanted to change this to the 3columns.phtml template...how could I do this